# How to evaluate the minimum cli version being compatible with a certain cloud foundry instance?

Tags: cloud-foundry

is there a way to evaluate the required minimum cf cli version for a specific cloud foundry instance? i can get the api version of the instance with `cf api`. in my case it is `2.92.0`. the cli version on my machine is `6.35.2+88a03e995.2018-03-15`. is there a command to find out the compatibililty of a cf cli version with a cf api version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the cf cli will do this automatically (you'll get a warning if your cli is too old), but if you want to look manually you can compare the version of your cf cli (i.e. `cf -v`) with the version listed on the `/v2/info` endpoint, specifically the `min_cli_version` attribute.  You'd need at least that version of the cf cli to interact with the deployment you're targeting.

Ex:

```
$ cf curl /v2/info
{
   "name": "",
   "build": "",
   "support": "https://support.run.pivotal.io",
   "version": 0,
   "description": "Cloud Foundry sponsored by Pivotal",
   "authorization_endpoint": "https://login.run.pivotal.io",
   "token_endpoint": "https://uaa.run.pivotal.io",
   "min_cli_version": "6.22.0",
   "min_recommended_cli_version": "latest",
   "api_version": "2.107.0",
   "app_ssh_endpoint": "ssh.run.pivotal.io:2222",
   "app_ssh_host_key_fingerprint": "e7:13:4e:32:ee:39:62:df:54:41:d7:f7:8b:b2:a7:6b",
   "app_ssh_oauth_client": "ssh-proxy",
   "doppler_logging_endpoint": "wss://doppler.run.pivotal.io:443",
   "routing_endpoint": "https://api.run.pivotal.io/routing"
}
```

or just `curl https://<target-host>/v2/info`.  Authentication isn't needed for this endpoint.